# Prevent wrapping in nested floated items in CSS

Tags: css, css-float, word-wrap

I have a div that contains many floated child items. Each child item is a div containing an input and a label. In Firefox it looks fine, but in IE7, the last item on a line is wrapped to fit, rather than being moved to the next line.

[Wrapped Items http://harriyott.com/images/wrapping.png](http://harriyott.com/images/wrapping.png)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried applying the white-space: nowrap; property to the labels?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Answer (score 1):

Minimize the browser window (e.g. Ctrl + - in google chrome) to the minimum and set the
"min-width: minValue in px" for the main "container" . .

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the width of each nested div.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how wide each one will be

Answer (score -2):

I dont know if  I understand correctly, but have you try the old trick:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```